# UICollectionView numberOfItemsInSection: called for each section in entire view when refreshing visible cells causing lag/freeze

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview

In my app I have a selection mode that allows for cells in a `UICollectionView` to be selected and then used for various actions. When I enable selection mode, I refresh the visible cells so that a selection mode indicator is displayed.  The sizing of the cells remains the same, and is set to be hard coded values (as well as the section header sizes) when I setup the `UICollectionView's` layout.

My `UICollectionView` has it's items organized into sections, using a `NSFetchedResultsController` as the underlying datasource.  The `NSFetchedResultsController` uses a section name value. The core data fetched with the `NSFetchedResultsController` contains many entires (sometimes over 100,000) and sections (sometimes over 5,000).

The core data aspect of this works nicely - the fetch is *somewhat* expensive, but overall reasonable.  I do not set a fetch limit FWIW (but doing so even with a fetch size as small as 25 I see no performance difference).

Despite the good core data performance, I experience UI lag/freeze when I enter selection mode. I did some profiling and I saw that when I enter selection mode, the `numberOfItemsInSection` method is called for each section.  Thus the app sometimes calls `numberOfItemsInSection` 5000 times when entering selection mode!  Each individual call is relatively lightweight but extrapolating that by 5000 results in the noticeable UI lag/freeze.  It appears that the `UICollectionViewController` is doing this as part of it's layout/update view logic, but I don't know why it needs to know about *all* of the sections...

I'm wondering WHY when using sections in my `UICollectionView` controller would I have to have `numberOfItemsInSection` called for each section - the size should be consistent, so why is the view being laid out again?

Comment: What mechanism are you using to "refresh the visible cells"? You may know that the total scroll height is unchanged but the collection view may not be able to make that assumption depending on what you've asked it to do.

Comment: In my experience it is usually the sectionNameKeyPath that is the most expensive part of the fetchedReusltsController. Are you sure you are not misreading the profiler?  Are you doing anything expensive in sectionNameKeyPath like creating a calendar?

Comment: FetchLimit is not respected by `NSFetchedResultsController` but you can do a limit by doing two fetches.  First you find what element is the last element you want to include by doing a fetch with a limit of 1 and a fetch​Offset of the limit.  Then use that element's date (or whatever you are using to sort by) to limit the predicate in the fetchedResultsController.  The collectionView will still get bigger than the limit as items are insert, but this does a good job of not loading everything when it is rarely needed.

Comment: @Jonah I am using the following API: `[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];`

Comment: @JonRose yes I totally agree.  If I remove the `sectionNameKeyPath` logic, this issue does not exist - but I suspect that's because the collection view only has 1 section and thus it does not need to call `numberOfItemsInSection` many many times.  The property that I use to for `sectionNameKeyPath` is a string value in my entity, and I do not do any logic when getting that value.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand I'm not sure why a call to `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` would cause the collection view to update it's section item counts.

One possible workaround: make sure your fetched results controller is caching your section data to avoid these item counts requiring expensive queries if you have no changes to your store.

> When you initialize an instance of NSFetched​Results​Controller, you typically specify a cache name. (If you do not specify a cache name, the controller does not cache data.) When you create a controller, it looks for an existing cache with the given name...

https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller#1661453